# how can i perform a Relationship in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I wanted to do something that is made in PHP to be able to make a model hasMany or belongsTo in xCode, in PHP, the code is like this (on the laravel framework):

```
public function eventos(){
    return->$this->belongsTo("nowparty/EventoModel")
}
```

But I really don't know how to perform that in swift, thanks.

P.D: if that needs to be done in firebase i'll really apreciate if someone could guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is an ORM (object-relational mapping) framework.

The Apple [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) framework has some ORM-like functionality, and may be what you're looking for. Otherwise, there are other options available, including (but not limited to) Firebase.

Comment: I'm using firebase, but i really don't know how to establish in the database the relationships